# Performance com Exists

Tags: sql, oracle, firebird

Um colega mencionou que ao fazer um `EXISTS` num SQL, é recomendado usar `DISTINCT 1` para melhorar a performance.
Por exemplo, ao invés de fazer:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM CLIENTES  
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CODCLI 
                     FROM VENDAS 
                    WHERE VENDAS.CODCLI = CLIENTES.CODCLI)
```

Ele sugeriu fazer:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM CLIENTES  
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT 1
                     FROM VENDAS 
                    WHERE VENDAS.CODCLI = CLIENTES.CODCLI)
```

Há diferença (performance) na execução dos SQL´s acima?
Qual seria recomendado?

Bancos: Oracle e FireBird (sistema multibanco).

Comment: Sql-Server ou Mysql?

Comment: Nas versões mais novas do Oracle é indiferente , em todo caso uso o "select null from" no subselect , em alguns casos no Oracle um hint é útil

Comment: @Sveen Editei a pergunta

Comment: Dependendo do Volume de dados acho que tem uma melhora performance do SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Em algumas tabelas, quando utilizar Joins, alguns valores podem ser duplicados em algumas relações, portanto ele tem que pesquisar em várias linhas dentro daquele mesmo cara, mas se você utilizar o distinct, ele vai apenas procurar a primeira vez aquele cara, não importando se aquele mesmo cara poderia ter uma outra versão em algum campo, então em tabelas com grande número de registros, acaba sendo mais rápido.

Vamos supor, você quer fazer um select na tabela de vendas, essa venda pertence a um cliente que tem dois tipos de contratos diferentes, mas os contrato do cliente não tem ligação direta com a venda, somente com o cliente, se você fizer uns joins até os contratos, ele vai duplicar as linhas da mesma venda, uma para cada contrato, e com o distinct ele vai procurar só no primeiro contrato e vai "pular" o segundo para não duplicar a mesma venda, agora imagine fazer um select em todas as vendas que entra em todos os clientes e passa por todos os contratos dos clientes... ficaria bem mais rápido.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/163211)

Comment: É complicado, quando surge uma pergunta nova que seja de um nível mais baixo, os analistas sr já respondem perfeitamente, o Stack Overflow não dá espaço para programadores iniciantes criar reputações, eu respondi pois ninguém estava ajudando o cara e eu tinha um bom conhecimento do assunto.

Answer (score -2):

Projeção dentro do exists não existe diferença nenhuma, os otimizadores de consultas são espertos o suficiente para executar da forma mais otimizada possível.

Fica a dica: Compare o plano de execução. A consulta pode ser escrita de diferentes formas mas se o plano de execução for o mesmo, então vc terá o mesmo resultado a nível de desempenho.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).